# Lego Mindstorms: gnu noSuchPortException after severl successful attempts

Tags: java, bluetooth, processing, rxtx, lego-mindstorms

In order to send direct commands to our Lego Mindstorms Robot, we use the NXTComm and the RXTXComm (for x64) libraries.

We are able multiple times to start our `Processing Applet` and call

```
LegoNXT robot = new LegoNXT(this, "COM6"); // this is a PApplet
robot.motorForward(1, 20); //e.g.
```

The robot makes clearly 2 sounds if it starts and 1 sound if the `PApplet` is closed, which I think are alerts for "robot connected" and "robot disconnected". However, after 4-5 successfull attempts, always following error appears:

```
gnu.io.NoSuchPortException
    at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(CommPortIdentifier.java:269)
    at pt.citar.diablu.nxt.protocol.NXTCommBluetoothSerialChannel.openPort(NXTCommBluetoothSerialChannel.java:82)
    at pt.citar.diablu.nxt.protocol.NXTCommBluetoothSerialChannel.<init>(NXTCommBluetoothSerialChannel.java:54)
    at pt.citar.diablu.processing.nxt.LegoNXT.<init>(LegoNXT.java:148)
    at project.FirstTry.setup(FirstTry.java:44)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(Unknown Source)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Even when this error appears, the "final sound" of the robot appears. Since now, we are only able to fix this by rebooting the computer. After this, the whole thing begins from new.

What can cause this error? Is there a way to "clean" the port connection?